# React Native(Android) Unhandled promise rejection - Network Request

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have recently created an Expo project that works perfectly fine on iOS / Web but on Android device I get the error described in the title.

What happens is that the app opens with a LogIn screen in witch on a button press I send a POST request to my server (hosted, not localhost)

The POST request looks like this:

```
_userLogin() {
        let username = this.state.username;
        let password = this.state.password;
      
        fetch("https://domain/login-react", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password,
          }),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          if(responseData.status == 1) {
              //saving user
            this.setState({isLoggedIn: responseData.status});
            this.setState({detaliiUser: responseData.detaliiUser});
            AsyncStorage.setItem('USER_ID',JSON.stringify(this.state.detaliiUser['Id']));
            
            //redirect to products page
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Liste Utilizator');
          }else{
            this.setState({mesajEroare: responseData.status});
          }
        })
      }
```

*I replaced the actual fetch URL for privacy reasons*

In my `app.json` the android permissions are configured as follows:

```
"android": {
      "permissions" : ["ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "CAMERA", "INTERNET"],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "app.htgps.listare"
    },
```

The error I get:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:527:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Another strange thing is that when I run `expo build:android` the app doesn't ask for any permission on the device I use for testing which runs 'Android 10'

I googled for the last 2 days and tried multiple possible solutions but couldn't find any that works for me.

I could use any help and I appreciate any form of advice.

Thanks in advance, CR

Comment: What do you see in the logs when you get this unhandled promise rejection?

Comment: Also this is an async call             AsyncStorage.setItem('USER_ID',JSON.stringify(this.state.detaliiUser['Id'])); did you try adding a await in the front?

Comment: Already fixed this situation by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to ./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, maybe you should try it ;)

Comment: @bsisic I don't have that folder because this is an expo basic app, all I can do is modify the app.json permissions

Comment: @Satheeshwaran but why does it work on iOS without the `await` ?

Comment: @Satheeshwaran regarding the complete error, what I get except the post title is : `http://IP/mode_modules - _CallTimer, _CallFunction, _guard`

Comment: The concerning part is that I don't get any permission prompt when I run the app on the testing device, it doesn't ask for any kind of access permission that is defined in `app.json` - `android:permissions[]`

Comment: OK isn't a bare project, so try to take off `INTERNET` from permissions in your app.json, isn't a regular permissions, by default an empty permissions array allow you to receive data from Internet

Comment: @bsisic
I removed `INTERNET` and the error I get is the same. See it in the edited post version

Comment: @Satheeshwaran I added the error in the original post, I edited it

Comment: Can you see what is coming up in the log cat on the native side of things? adb logcat and paste the output.